# Firebase auth not working with multiple tabs in Chrome?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to make a web app that uses Firebase auth for login. I'm using SvelteKit and logging in using "signInWithRedirect". When my app is running in multiple tabs, the login flow sometimes breaks.

To replicate:

1. Start a fresh sveltekit project (for example with "npm create svelte@latest my-test").
2. Run "npm install".
3. Run "npm install firebase".
4. Start a new Firebase project with the auth module included. Or use an existing project.
5. Paste firebase config into "const firebaseConfig" in "+page.svelte".
6. Run "npm run dev".
7. Open several tabs in Chrome and press sign in/out a few times in the different tabs.

Check the Network tab of the Dev tools for more information.

After a while, the login flow breaks. Is there something wrong with my code or is this a bug? Note, I didn't manage to replicate this in Edge, only in Chrome and Brave.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { signOut, getAuth, signInWithRedirect, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged, type User } from "firebase/auth";
    import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

    const firebaseConfig = {
        // PASTE FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
        // PASTE FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
        // PASTE FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
        // PASTE FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
        // PASTE FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
        // PASTE FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
    };

    async function handleSignout() {
        await signOut(auth);
    }

    async function handleSignin() {
        await signInWithRedirect(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider())
    }

    function createFirebaseApp() {
        try {
            return getApp();
        } catch {
            return initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }
    }

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = createFirebaseApp();
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    const db = getFirestore(app);

    let user: User|null;
    
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (data) => {
        user = data;
    })

</script>

<h1>Auth bug replication</h1>
<p>To replicate the bug, open multiple tabs and log in and out several times. After a while, the flow breaks. I could replicate the bug in Chrome and Brave, but not Edge.</p>

<div>
    {#if user}
        <span>{user.displayName}</span>
        <input type="button" value="Sign out" on:click={handleSignout} />
    {:else}
        <input type="button" value="Sign in with Google" on:click={handleSignin} />
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the login flow breaks"?  If there is an error, you should show that in your question (look at the console logs) and identify the line of code that caused it.

Comment: After the user has signed in successfully, where does the `user` object get saved? Because it looks like its just a variable called `user` (You'll lose it on refresh). Are you saving the `user` object to a cookie? svelte/store? localStorage? or sessionStorage? etc?